# How to find the value of $\inf_x \frac{\sum_{1 \le i<j \le n}a_{ij}(x_i-x_j)^2}{\sum_{1 \le i<j \le n}b_{ij}(x_i-x_j)^2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, inequality

How to find the value of $\inf_x \frac{\sum_{1 \le i<j \le n}a_{ij}(x_i-x_j)^2}{\sum_{1 \le i<j \le n}b_{ij}(x_i-x_j)^2}$, where $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $a_{ij},b_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ are given positive real number? I can only found lower bound $\min_{1 \le i<j \le n}\frac{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}}$ for this term, can we found the exact minimum and the $x$ achives this minimum or can we derive a sharper lower bound for this term? I really appreciate all the answers.